# Logging module, ValueError: incomplete format key

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, logging

Here's my code:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='formsINFO.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

now = datetime.datetime.now()
s = now.strftime("%d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S")
logging.info("Time of testrun: {}".format(s))
```

Here's the error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 992, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 838, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 578, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 547, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 391, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
ValueError: incomplete format key
Call stack:
  File "C:\Users\Form_Catch.py", line 38, in <module>
    logging.info("Time of testrun: {}".format(s))
Message: 'Time of testrun: 12 July 2018, 14:56:12'
Arguments: ()
```

I googled for an hour plus but I couldn't find the solution... Adding in `formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s : %(message)s')` (a solution from an old post) didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is that you've used a reserved logging format character `:` between your `levelname` and `message`.
Try and replace this with a `-` and this should work.

[Python docs: format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)